# Crystal Reports ExportToDisk font size

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports, .net-1.0

When using the `ExportToDisk` method of `ReportDocument` it shrinks all of the fonts to 0.5pt than they were specified in the report.  I'm creating a word document so specified the line of code as such:

```
myReport.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.[Shared].ExportFormatType.WordForWindows, path)
```

I've also experimented with creating a RTF instead (using `ExportFormatType.RichText`) but to no avail.  I seem to remember coming across a reason with a registry fix - but I've lost it now.

Must warn you this is a legacy system (.NET 1)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

RTF format is a text file whose format is documented. You should easily be able to postprocess it to adjust any font properties. You can [download the spec](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fdownloads%2Fdetails.aspx%3FFamilyId%3DDD422B8D-FF06-4207-B476-6B5396A18A2B&ei=ACRJTZGAAo_ksQOStZHACg&usg=AFQjCNGBztYlDH_pxkhCLUOES4972wNepQ&sig2=IfJt7AvcRZD2BpygCnRZdQ) from Microsoft for further info.

Comment: Now it's a dead link.