# Forcing MSWord to open a document with a set font (ignoring the one within the file)

Tags: fonts, ms-word, font-size

As per my previously ([unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863777/crystal-reports-exporttodisk-font-size)) I'm exploring a different path.

Is it possible to force MS Word to ignore the font size within a file and apply its own when the file is being opened?  I understand this could get messy (registry hacks etc) but I would like to know of its feasibility.

Comment: It is possible in Word to find and replace fonts either manually or with VBA, would something on these lines suit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ForEachLoop's answer is about right, there is no way to launch word in such a way as to cause it to replace fonts, or any other formatting. You'll have to launch an autostart macro of some sort to reformat the doc automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in a code module of the document, or code module in a template attached or opened by the document:

```
Public Sub AutoOpen()
    ActiveDocument.Range.Font.Size = 20
End Sub
```